# add null check for an array in dataweave

Tags: arrays, json, xml, mule, dataweave

I am converting json to xml and i am getting array with one more inside array for  that array,  I am not able to set null check for  inner array , getting script error in dataweave , i have attached sample Json request and XML  response.

```
{"test":[ {
                   "GroupId": "3",
                  "forms": [{
                           "formId": "2"
                    } ]
    },
 {   "GroupId": "3"
           ]
    } ]}
```

and this sample xml I am generating

```
<test>
<myforms>
<GroupId>3</GroupId>
<formId>2</formId>
</myforms>
<myforms>
<GroupId>7</GroupId>
<formId>8</formId>
</myforms>
</test>
```

and My DW script is below

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/xml
---
{
    (test: {
        (payload.test map {
            myforms: {
                GroupId: $.GroupId as :number,

                (($.forms map {

                    formId:$.formId

                })) when payload.test.forms !=null



            }
        })
    }) when payload.test !=null
}
```

**Issue Is**:- I am not able put null check for inner array i.e  when payload.test.forms !=null
it is throwing an script error , below snapshot with error mark of dataweave , Please tell how set null check for inner array  loop

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That's because of your syntax you are getting such errors.
Can you try `default []`,  something like this :

```
($.forms default [] map {

                    formId:$.formId

                })
```

That will help to get your expected result

Comment: I have implemented your soloution but fould one more issue can you check below url for more details

https://forums.mulesoft.com/questions/78062/set-null-condition-for-json-aray-in-dataweave.html?childToView=79252#comment-79252

Thnaks

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code:-

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/xml
---
{
    test : {
         (payload.test map {
            myforms : {
                GroupId: $.GroupId as :number,
                 ($.forms default [] map {

                   formId : $.formId

                })
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: I have implemented your soloution but fould one more issue can you check below url for more details

https://forums.mulesoft.com/questions/78062/set-null-condition-for-json-aray-in-dataweave.html?childToView=79252#comment-79252

Thnaks

Comment: I am not sure how are you mapping forms array, but you can give below dw a try..

or share the dw you are using it your code it will make it easier to understand how are you mapping it..


%dw 1.0
%output application/xml
---
{
    test : {
         (payload.test map {
            myforms : {
                GroupId: $.GroupId as :number,
                 ($.forms default [] map {

                   formId : $.formId,
(RoatationId : $.RoatationId) when $.RoatationId? and $.RoatationId !=null

                })
            }
        })
    }
}

Comment: Thanks for your Response , let me check